# identify second row, third column of a table with jquery

Tags: jquery, selector

How can I identify second row, third column of a table.
I expect something like this should work

```
var mySection = $('table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)');
```

Comment: Did you try it? Does it work?

Comment: yes. not behaving as expected.

Comment: Can you give an example? (Ideally via http://jsfiddle.net/). Also, how is not behaving as expected? By sharing some of this info, you make it much easier for people to help.

Comment: Grep some code in my site, I use $("table").find("tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)") and it works...

Answer (score 2):

The selector posted in the question [works](http://jsfiddle.net/mkRCZ/1/) for me.  Check out the jsfiddle.  I have it coloring the `mySection` text red in that example.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a second parameter to jQuery(), this will specify the context.

```
var my section = $('td:nth-child(3)', 'table tr:nth-child(2)')
```

Though, come to think of it, it will create the same results as what was originally posted:

```
var my section = $('table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)')
```

Answer (score 0):

another way,

```
$('table tr:eq(1) td:eq(2)');
```

Answer (score 0):

var mysection =$('#tableId tr:eq(2) td:eq(2)')